# Are there any tools for working with collections in functional style in Qt?

Tags: qt, collections, functional-programming

Are there any tools for working with collections in functional style in Qt? Something like

```
SomeCollection c = Collections::map(collection, func);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the usual STL algorithms with Qt containers the same way as you do with STL containers. Here's a [list of algorithms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) in STL.

The STL version of `map` would be [std::transform](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform).

If you're able to use C++11 in your project, you can combine them with [lambda functions](http://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).